# The declared package does not match the expected package ""

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse and have not used Java for sometime. However, I can compile my code on the command-line just fine and generate the necessary `.class` files. In Eclipse, it complains that `The declared package "Devices" does not match the expected package ""`. What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Sample code:

```
package Devices;

public final class DevFrequency 
{
    public short messageID;
    public double frequency;
    public short converterID;
    public DevFrequency() 
    {
    }
    public DevFrequency(short _messageID,double _frequency,short _converterID)
    {
        messageID = _messageID;
        frequency = _frequency;
        converterID = _converterID;
    }
}
```

The name of my project is `DeviceDDS`.

Comment: Is this class in the `/src/Converters` directory?

Comment: If you're going to change your question retrospectively (which seems pointless, to be honest) you need to be consistent about it - you haven't edited the first paragraph of the question. You've also made all the comments look odd. Why change everything, nearly a year and a half later?

Comment: In my case (using VSCode Java Project Manager extension), for some reasons, I had to manually change the class' package, or you could hold the mouse pointer on the red line beneath the error and then hit "quick fix" to do it automatically. (Of course I have no idea how this happened because the VSCode Java Project Manager handles this when you create a new folder, on its own and I couldn't replicate this behavior once again). Anyways.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Eclipse expects the declared package to match the directory hierarchy - so it's expecting your Java file to be in a directory called "Devices" under your source root. At the moment it looks like the file is directly in your source root. So create the appropriate directory, and move the file in there.

Note that conventionally, packages are in lower case and include your organization name in reverse DNS order, e.g.

```
com.foo.devices;
```

Comment: @Sakti: You can't as far as I'm aware, and I'd strongly advise you not to even if you could. *All* experienced Java developers will expect you to follow the normal conventions.

Answer (score 186):

**Try closing and re-opening the file.**

It is possible to get this error in eclipse when there is absolutely nothing wrong with the file location or package declaration.  Try that before spending a lot of time trying these other solutions.  Sometimes eclipse just gets confused.  It's worked for me on a number of occasions.  I credit [the idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997524/the-declared-package-does-not-match-the-expected-package/25220460#comment22929069_12110407) to [Joshua Goldberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411282/joshua-goldberg).

Comment: Had this problem with a Gradle project inside VS Code. Re-open fixed it.

Comment: opening and closing the file in the eclipse editor helped solving the issue. 
I had added a source folder in java config build - source tab, the error did not removed, but when I closed and opened the editor in eclipse, it helped . :-)

Comment: Exiting and restarting eclipse fixed the problem too.

Comment: he he .. I spent an hour trying to fix it and then saw this.

Comment: @candied_orange Thank you. closing and opening the file multiple times fixed it for me as well

Comment: It happened to me with Vim and CoC and coc-java LSP after I moved some stuff around. Restarting vim solved the problem.

Comment: ha ha wasn't expecting this to work for me, thanks btw.

Comment: @candied_orange Good idea to try closing and reopening the file. It looks like this worked for a lot of people. But it did not work for me.

Comment: I hate that this was the solution

Comment: You just saved me a big amount of shame and time

Answer (score 49):

**Solution 1 :** One solution that worked for me when this error  "**The declared package does not match the expected package**"  occured for a project I checked-out from eclipse CVS :

1.Right click the project in the navigation bar and click 'delete'
2.Make sure '**Delete project contents on disk**' option is **NOT** checked, and click OK.
3.Now after the project is deleted, go to **File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace**
4.Select your workspace from the directory listing and check the box next to your project name. Click '**Finish**'

**Solution 2 :** Once again I got this error with the following message

*Eclipse build errors - java.lang.Object cannot be resolved*
I had to follow another route mention here and the error went away.

In the mean time, the work around is to remove the JRE System Library from the project and then add it back again. 
Here are the steps:

1. Go to properties of project with the build error (right click > Properties) View the "Libraries" tab in the "Build Path" section Find the "JRE System Library" in the list (if this is missing then this error message is not an eclipse bug but a mis-configured project)
2. Remove the "JRE System Library"
3. Hit "Add Library ...", Select "JRE System Library" and add the appropriate JRE for the project (eg. 'Workspace default JRE')
4. Hit "Finish" in the library selection and "OK" in the project properties and then wait for the re-build of the project

Hopefully the error will be resolved ...

Comment: I had to do this too (adding a directory of groovy tests to the build).  Don't forget to make notes on your run configurations, which you'll need to recreate.  Any idea why this is needed?  Such a pain.

Comment: Simpler solution: I was in this situation again, and was able to get it working by closing the project, restarting Eclipse, and re-opening the project.

Comment: Even simpler!  I just had it again, and it went away by closing and re-opening the single problematic file's editor.

Comment: Restarting eclipse seems to fix it.

Comment: Solution 1 worked for me.  Very weird.  I have imported the same git clone into Eclipse on other machines and not seen this problem.

Comment: This issue is still present in Eclipse Luna, where none of these two solutions functions. However, [the restart suggested by Joshua Goldberg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997524/the-declared-package-does-not-match-the-expected-package#comment21950896_12110407) does it.

Comment: Solution #2 is pathetic :D
"have you tried turning it on and off, again?"

Comment: Solution 1 worked. This is funny but it worked perfectly

Comment: The first solution worked for me. Just wondering somebody can detail out why it happens as such?

Comment: Solution 2 worked for me. Thanks a lot. You saved me smashing up my laptop.

Comment: Sol #1 is worked for me. thanks lot

Answer (score 17):

I resolved the problem by following these steps:

1. Select the project - Right click - java build path.
2. In source tab - you change the `src` to `src/main/java`.
3. Eclipse will reorder all the project.

Answer (score 12):

I had this problem - the other classes within my package were fine, but one class had the error against it. There was nothing wrong with the package declaration.

I fixed it by doing `refactor->move` and moved the class to another package temporarily, then `refactor->move` back to the original package.

Answer (score 4):

I fix it just changing the name to lowercase and now Eclipse recognizes the package.

Comment: It worked for VSCode too, thanks.
but why exactly this was throwing error, and How this First_char_capitalization made it work?
could you please tell?

Answer (score 3):

This problem got resolved by mentioning the **package** name

I moved my file **Test_Steps.java** which was under package **stepDefinition**

[image]

by just adding the **package stepDefinition** the problem got resolved

So this problem can occur when you have a package and you are not using in your class file.

Adding it has resolved the problem and the error was no longer appearing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create a new package under your project called "Devices" and place your class in it. This is equivalent to the class being placed in a directory called "Devices" in your project source folder.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the class inside a folder `Devices`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `Devices` is defined as a source folder in the project properties.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same kind of error but my package was absolutely correct. When I just closed and opened my editor, the error disappears. Hope this might help in some scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by removing an "excluding" attribute for that package in my `.classpath` file. Remove the attribute, not the whole tag, or "src/java" will cease to be a source folder.

```
<classpathentry excluding="com/myproject/mypackage/mysubpackage/" kind="src" path="src/java"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that You have created a correct package.You might get a chance to create folder instead of package

Answer (score 0):

1. Create directory [your.project.name] in workspace root directory of your project.
2. Copy *.java from "src" to that directory.
3. Close and reopen project.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I was checking out a project from an svn repository in eclipse. There were jar files in my .m2 folder that eclipse wasn't looking at. To fix the issue I did:

right click project folder Configure > Convert to Maven Project

and that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There are a million answers, but here's another one:
copy the files into a new package, delete the old package and rename the new package to the old package's name.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using default package. Create a new package with name 'devices' and copy this code inside it and use.

Answer (score 0):

I had have this sort situations when I copied classes from other packages/projects.

Menu->Project->Clean usually helps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I selected the error marker in the Problems tab and deleted it since the Java's file main method was being executed correctly. That is some glitch in Eclipse Neon with the multitude of plugins it has installed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue too when I had imported an existing project to eclipse. It was a gradle project, but while importing I imported it as regular project by clicking General-> Existing Projects into Workspace. To resolve the issue I've added Gradle nature to the project by 
  :::: Right click on Project folder -> Configure-> Add Gradle Nature

Answer (score 0):

I was using Spring Tool Suite 4. Not able to figure out the issue. The directory structure was according to the package name.

> But cleaning the project helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a maven project in Eclipse IDE. I was able to resolve it by replacing the .classpath file with the correct format. After replacing close and open the project.

**Sample .classpath file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/webapp">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="test" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check your Java 'build path' in the project properties, if the 'source' directory (path) is not properly setup in there, then this will cause this error to occur for all the classes therein.

So the path *must* specify the 'root' (containing) directory in which the sources within the package exists ...

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that we can do is
On the error, ctrl+enter and move the file to the expected package

Answer (score 0):

In my case  being used **gradle**, it happend due to wrong name  in **settings.gradle**. Rename `rootProject.name = 'somename'` to actual name of your project folder. Cleanup it all with `topbar->project->clean`....

And you are done my friend!

(Also I've reset values in `build.gradle` to latest versions but that just for case)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in VS Code. Changing the package name, then changing it back to the correct name, then saving, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue in Visual Studio Code.
In my case, there were 2 Java Projects in the Project Manager for Java extension. Those could be seen on the bottom left under JAVA PROJECTS.
I had to delete the one which was not Mavenized.
I did this by clicking on the far right three dots in the same line as JAVA PROJECTS, and selecting Clean Workspace. And then Reload and delete.
After that, all the Java files in the project where correct without the package errors.