# Sinch Sample Apps Error in Package Name

Tags: java, android, sinch

I'm trying to run the messaging sample app in the Sinch 3.0.1 SDK. In the src files, this line:

```
package com.sinch.android.rtc.sample.pstn;
```

throws an error. The error reads:

> The declared package "com.sinch.android.rtc.sample.messaging" does not
>   match the expected package
>   "main.java.com.sinch.android.rtc.sample.messaging"

However, if I change the package name to main.java.com.sinch.android.rtc.sample.messaging like the error suggests, the variable 'R' cannot be resolved anywhere in my app.

The same error patterns happens in the other 2 sample apps as well.

EDIT - I figured out how to fix this but don't have enough karma to answer.

I read in [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997524/the-declared-package-does-not-match-the-expected-package) that Eclipse expects the package name to match the parent folder's name.

So, once I changed the package name, all I had to was was rename the parent folder to match! See screenshot if I explained this badly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJUUh.png

Comment: I will add it to the answer, thanks for being patient.

Answer (score 0):

See above for explanation. Thanks mravca
I figured out how to fix this but don't have enough karma to answer.

I read in this stack overflow answer that Eclipse expects the package name to match the parent folder's name.

So, once I changed the package name, all I had to was was rename the parent folder to match! See screenshot if I explained this badly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcRNF.png