# Folder path != package name

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I cloned the [sms-backup-plus](https://github.com/jberkel/sms-backup-plus) repository. This is the repository folder structure by eclipse.

[image: eclipse-folderstructure]

But the package name in the project is `com.zegoggles.smssync;`. So i got error `declared package does not match the expected package`. How i avoid main/java append in package name.

PS: Android studio works correctly

**Update:** Production code on main/java/com/zegoggles/smssync and test code on test/java/com/zegoggles/smssync. So i can't rename package name in source files.

Comment: right click and allow eclipse to fix it for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12110407/2741586 recommended way

Comment: @ScaryWombat But lot of java files are there. And i don't want change source code. I want sync with repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is happening, as your eclipse is not recognizing maven project. Do the following

- Open command prompt and navigate to your workspace location.
- Execute command **mvn eclipse:eclipse**. Make sure that your MAVEN_HOME is configured in environment variables before executing this command.

Answer (score 0):

THe package name and the directory structure are expected to be the same.  Just do a refactor->rename on the packages and take off the main.java

Comment: Folder structure is main/java/com/zegoggles/smssync. i update my question

Comment: That's a bad way of structuring your repository.  You should be branching from the root, not just the source code-  otherwise you can't test changes to assets or manifest files, because they're shared.  Your method will not work with Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the base source directory for the project by opening the `Properties` for the project, go to `Java Build Path` and select the `Source` tab. Change `src` to be `src/main`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select your root package (main.java.com.zegoggles.smssync) in your case
2. Refactor -> Rename using Alt+Shift+R
3. Replace the existing package name to com.zegoggles.smssync
4. Select "Update References" & "Rename Subpackages" checkboxes below.
5. Project -> Clean from Eclipse

Comment: If i do files inside the "main/java/com/zegoggles/smssync" and "test/java/com/zegoggles/smssync" will be treated as same