# The declared package "" does not match the expected package "src" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I originally had all my .java files under a file named "GravityBallz", but I then created a folder called "src" inside the GravityBallz folder and put them all in there. Now it's giving me an error. I tried restarting but still didn't work.

Thanks

[So here is the src folder I added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Kb3b.png)

[And here are all the problems I'm getting for all the .java files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzPs1.png)

Comment: Can you add more details about what your project looks like, what error you are getting? maybe use some screenshots to show the problem

Comment: Just added pictures, hope it's clear. Thanks

Comment: Ah, can you check the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997524/the-declared-package-does-not-match-the-expected-package/25220460

Answer (score 1):

Because you had put your java file in 'src' folder, so you need to add "package src" in every java file.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get rid of those errors without having to declare a `package src;` in every file, you must be familiar with a very simple concept: **The Java Classpath**.

Most Java IDEs or Environments like the one used by VSCode, search up the source files of your project under a directory called the "ClassPath".

In the Java programing language, [the classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath) is commonly passed by a java parameter or an environment variable, and it's the directories of your project where the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) looks up the `.class` and `.java` files.

[Example of a .classpath file generated by Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC7Vf.png)

Note that in the image, there are the "src" and "bin" directories, that correspond to the source files and compiled class files respectively.

You can modify this path association in different ways depending on your IDE or Environment. Particularly, in VSCode you can search in the command pallette: "`> Java: Configure Classpath`"

[Example of a project with a configured source classpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m9vf.png)

[The project structure itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QOyt.png)

it will bring you to a simple but useful interface that allows you to select the project you want to configure and all the different directories where you may store your source files and your compiled class files.

That will allow you to configure the project structure just the way you want it to.