# R cannot resolved to a variable in android

Tags: android, variables, resources

I know this question is asked many times. But still that answers are not resolved my problem. My code shows an error "R cannot resolved to a variable in android". I cleaned and build automatically many times and also fix the project properties but the error still same. How can I resolve this error ?? please help me and thanks

Comment: there is problem with your layout or any another xml, also try to work with correct import in your java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look for the errors in `res` folder and resolve it first.

It can be an error in layout, drawable, values etc..

Comment: I want to include feedback in my app..so i need to show a popup to send mail and..i need to enter my mail id and feedback and when i am clicking the send button in the popup,the mail must send to the predefined mail id..how it is possible???

Comment: you should ask a different question for this and you will get a lot of replies.

Answer (score 1):

Check the last **layout, drawable, values etc** where you made changes prior to getting errors. You must have made an error there. It usually is using `captial letters` or `-` in drawables or import to "R" in your activity or some problems in xml like name `match_parent` to `Match_parent` etc. Here are some links with similar problems

[Android Development- Where is my R.Java file?](http://www.mybringback.com/travis-android-help/1/hello-world/)

- [R cannot be resolved - Android error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)
- [R cannot be resolved to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592806/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable)
- [R cannot be resolved to a variable -- mailing list entry](http://www.anddev.org/sdk-adt-emulator-problems-f16/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable-t52607.html)
- [Fixed: R cannot be resolved to a variable](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/05/fixed-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-variable.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these.

1>Could be a problem in your xml
2>right click on the project->Android tools->Fix Project Properties (check if the build target is checked)
3>SDK update (Build tools would have not been downloaded) go to android sdk manager and download tools (to find out create a new project if it cannot resolve R then go ahead with this step.)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove "import android.R ;" at the top of your code.