# Trying to make a flipping card in an android application

Tags: android, viewflipper, flip, knapsack-problem, flipview

I'm trying for 2 weeks now to create a flipping layout in an android app, but nothing.. all the tutorials on the internet I've read, but nothing.. please, could someone, please, help me with this.. this is my Flippingactivity:

```
package com.ad;
import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.app.Activity;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
AnimationListener {

       private Animation animation1;
       private Animation animation2;
       private boolean isBackOfCardShowing = true;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.to_middle);
             animation1.setAnimationListener(this);
             animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.from_middle);
             animation2.setAnimationListener(this);
             findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
       }
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
              v.setEnabled(false);
              ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).clearAnimation();
              ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setAnimation(animation1);
              ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).startAnimation(animation1);
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
              if (animation==animation1) {
                     if (isBackOfCardShowing) {
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(R.drawable.card_front2);
                       } else {
        ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(R.drawable.card_back);
                       }
                       ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).clearAnimation();
         ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setAnimation(animation2);
         ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).startAnimation(animation2);
                 } else {
                        isBackOfCardShowing=!isBackOfCardShowing;
                        findViewById(R.id.button1).setEnabled(true);
                 }
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
}
```

Ok. So the problems: 1. At the setContentView, if I put my activity_main, it says that it can not be resolved or it is no a field.. 2. They are not recognizing my anim folder where I was the transition.. I created the anim folder in /res, but they still not recognising my xmls files.. 3. At R.id.imageView1 they are not recognising my image id too..

I tried: clean the project.. nothing. Refresh the /res before making the xmls.. nothing. Importing .R in many different ways.. nothing.. nothing.. nothing. HELP !

So. I'am backing someone who knows what's happening to help me, I'am exhausted of trying, and trying but nothing. PLEASE, please, please, help me a little bit.Thanks, and I'll be grateful. Have a nice day !!!

Comment: If you rename your layout file to something else does it work? Could be that references are not generating.

Comment: There is a similar post i've answered to, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592806/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable/18956051#18956051 please try it out. it might be helpful

Comment: I tried all.. nothing, nothing and nothing.. i think i'll get depresed .. that's a damn think..

Comment: do you have multiple packages in your workspace?

Comment: No.. Only the default and the package where is R.java...

Comment: Remove this import 'import android.R;' clean and build the project.

Comment: Its the same..i deleted the project..i recreated ..but still the same errors.. from beginning again.. nobody can help me again :| .. i'am desperate...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post enough information to fully understand the problem you are having, but i'm guessing that [this training article](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html) will help you.

Comment: What do you want to know more? Tell me and i'll specify exactly what you want to know for helping me. I tried that tutorial too...but its not exactly what I want..This are my issues: 1. At the setContentView, if I put my activity_main, it says that it can not be resolved or it is no a field.. 2. They are not recognizing my anim folder where I was the transition.. I created the anim folder in /res, but they still not recognising my xmls files.. 3. At R.id.imageView1 they are not recognising my image id too..